# Using Rickshaw/D3 in Node.js,for server side, raw svg accessible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, rickshaw

I'm trying to use D3 and Rickshaw in Node.  The service must create a time-series graph, and then transform the raw SVG into a png using a child process running imagemagick.  I really just need a raw svg string to do my conversion.  **Does rickshaw have any way to access a raw SVG string?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rickshaw uses `d3` internally and you can get the SVG string just like you would in a real DOM:

```
var Rickshaw = require('rickshaw'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env({
    features: { QuerySelector: true },
    html: '<html><body><div id="graph"></div></body></html>',
    done: function (err, window) {
        this.window = window;
        this.document = window.document;
        // classListShim(window.self); // <-- see comment below

        var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph({
            series: [ { data: [ { x: 0, y: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 4 }] } ],
            renderer: 'area',
            element: window.document.querySelector('#graph')
        });

        graph.render();
        // This will output the `svg` element in HTML format.
        console.log(window.document.querySelector('#graph').innerHTML);
    }
});
```

However, because curretly [`jsdom` does not support `classList`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/510), you'll need to use the [`classList` shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList) applied on `window.self`.

Complete code: https://gist.github.com/musically-ut/9154438